# How to properly implement JOIN/ UNION ALL in a query when selecting columns from all tables in a database?

Tags: sql

Assume I have many tables in a database.

[image]

I'm trying to select all tables with their max value of `TimeLoaded`. `TimeLoaded` is a timestamp. So my output should be similar to this:

[image]

Since I am trying to select every table in the database while retrieving the max value of `TimeLoaded`, I am unsure how to implement JOIN and UNION ALL as there may be a database with 20 or more tables.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do but I very much doubt it would make sense to do this via joins. I'd just write a separate `select "TableName", max(TimeLoaded) as TimeLoaded from TableName` then just union the results

Comment: Doesn't sound like joins are involved. You write a 20-way union if you've got 20 tables.

Comment: Hello @DavidWaterworth. I am trying to select a common column of 20 or more tables in a database to compare their max values. I'm trying to find a way to do this without having to write a union for every table in the database.

Comment: You can probably find the names of the tables that contain that column by querying the system catalogue (how will depend on what server you're using - i.e. MSSQL, MYSQL etc) but you'll still need to write a query to do the union.

Comment: Or probably a better design would be to have 1 table containing the name of each table, the TimeLoaded and update that when you load the tables. That way you just have to query 1 table.

Comment: SQL isn't really designed to support queries with dynamic table names, in general, its expected that you know the schema when you execute the query. You're trying to combine schema discovery with query execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know how to select table name, but maybe you can try this:

```
 SELECT TOP (1) MAX(TimeLoaded) as TimeLoaded, 'Arrival' AS Tables FROM [your_db_name].[dbo].[Arrival]
 Union 
 SELECT TOP (1) MAX(TimeLoaded) as TimeLoaded, 'Duration' AS Tables FROM [your_db_name].[dbo].[Duration]
 Union 
 SELECT TOP (1) MAX(TimeLoaded) as TimeLoaded, 'Departure' AS Tables FROM [your_db_name].[dbo].[Departure]
 Union 
 SELECT TOP (1) MAX(TimeLoaded) as TimeLoaded, 'Alert' AS Tables FROM [your_db_name].[dbo].[Alert]
```